# Can not Soft delete multiple rows using Query Builder

Tags: laravel-5

My model is something like this:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Photo extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

_ I can soft delete using:

```
$\App\Photo::find(1)->delete();
```

_ It does not work when I try to use soft delete on multiple rows:

```
\App\Photo::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->delete();
```

Does any one know why?

Comment: this should work in laravel 5.6. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/soft-delete-multiple-items-collection

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't soft delete multiple rows.
The only Laravel way is the `DB` facade in this case.
Here is how I would soft delete multiple rows.

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id', [array of ids])
            ->update([
                'deleted_at' => now()
            ]);
```

or

```
ModelName::whereIn('id', [array of ids])
           ->update(['deleted_at' => now()]);
```

Instead of `whereIn` you can put in any where condition like you usually put and can update the `deleted_at` key. Soft delete is nothing but marking the column as deleted.

This is also a very efficient solution rather than running soft delete for each model inside a loop which can crash the system if there're too many items in the array.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow this, but it can't trash multiple rows selected, it only delete a rows, but when I load a page again, all the rows of data I've deleted appear again. Why?

Comment: If you're getting the data using model, make sure that you've added `softDeletes` trait in the model. If you're using `DB` facade to fetch data, make sure to add the filter `whereNotNull('deleted_at')`

Answer (score 2):

The soft delete functionality only works on an instance of the Eloquent model itself. When you are doing this:

```
\App\Photo::find(1)->delete();
```

You are actually first retrieving the Photo with an ID of 1 from the database which is then prepared and made available as an instance of the Eloquent model (which can then use soft delete).

However, when you do this:

```
\App\Photo::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->delete();
```

You are not actually retrieving anything from the database, you are basically just preparing DELETE SQL in a more convenient way. This effectively runs something like:

```
DELETE FROM `photos` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3);
```

This is different from something like:

```
foreach (\App\Photo::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->get() as $photo) {

    $photo->delete();  # $photo is an eloquent model and can soft-delete

}
```

Notice the **->get()** which is actually grabbing data from the database first and will make it available as a collection of Eloquent models (which then *can* soft delete).

I don't think you can soft-delete a batch. In my foreach example using ->get() I imagine multiple queries are executed - something like:

```
UPDATE `photos` SET `deleted_at` = NOW() WHERE `id` = 1;
UPDATE `photos` SET `deleted_at` = NOW() WHERE `id` = 2;
UPDATE `photos` SET `deleted_at` = NOW() WHERE `id` = 3;
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found out that my boot function missing
    parent::boot();
In my case, this causes my code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
\App\Photo::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])
    ->get()
    ->map(function($photo) {
        $photo->delete();
    });
```